# I coded a program to check whether the matrix is symmetric or not. It works one way but not in other way although both seem correct

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array

Please find the required code below.

The way that doesn't work:

```
    int isSy = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)  {
            if (r[i][j] = trans[i][j])
                isSy = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isSy == 1)
        printf("The given matrix is symmetric.");
    else {
        printf("The given matrix is not symmetric.");
    }
```

The way that works:

```
    int isSy = 1;
    for (i = 0;i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if (r[i][j] != trans[i][j])
                isSy = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isSy == 1)
       printf("The given matrix is symmetric.");
    else {
        printf("The given matrix is not symmetric.");
    }
```

where `r` is the actual matrix and `trans` is its transpose.

Comment: Change `(r[i][j]=trans[i][j])` to `(r[i][j]==trans[i][j])`

Comment: @john not working man!!!

Comment: your `break` is not inside the `if`, you should put some braces around `isSy=1` and `break`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you observe the statement`if (r[i][j]=trans[i][j])` it is not a comparison but assignment statement.

```
 if (r[i][j]==trans[i][j])
         isSy=1;
         break;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (r[i][j]==trans[i][j])
   {
         isSy=1;
   }
   break;
```

And hence loop breaks irrespective of the condition check
I assume logic should be something like below snippet,

```
int isSy=1;
  for (i=0;i<row;i++)
  {
    for (j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
      if (r[i][j]!=trans[i][j]) {
          isSy=0;
          break; //only inner loop
        }
    }
    if(isSy==0)
    {
        break; //breaks outer loop
    }
  }
  if (isSy==1)
    printf("The given matrix is symmetric.");
  else
  {
    printf("The given matrix is not symmetric.");
  }
```

Try to add braces for more clarity and readability of your code